# openSSL using Android's NDK problems

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, android-ndk-r7

I have the following situation, 
I am porting a piece of an app using OpenSSL for AES encryption, I have everything compile, but the linker fails. The situation is the following: 
1. I wrote a JNI wrapper that simply does :

```
private native String cipherString(String plainData, int datasize, String password, int passSize);
private native String decipherString(String cipheredData, int datasize, String password, int passSize);
```

next I have a c++ file which I call that has the proper JNI sintax which translates jstring to char * and all other needed transformations, and makes a call to another cpp file which actually imports openssl headers (present and accounted for) and calls openssl methods for ciphering and deciphering.

So when I call ndk-build, it builds all thumbs, so the compiler compiles them correctly. 
next i needed to port openssl for android, and I used this [OpenSSL for Android](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android)
which works like a char with a simple ndk-build (in the root of the project, ofcourse) and builds the libssl.so and libcrypto.so

So I need to connect the two.. I find it a challenge to connect the build scripts, so that one ndk-build compiles and linkes everything (I would appreciate a simple example project if someone has the time for it)

so I copied the compiled libssl and libcrypto .so files in jni/includes/prebuilt and want to include them in the project for the linker to be able to finally create the lib which I will use at the end.

I have the following Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes/build/common.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes/build/common_includes.mk
APP_STL := gnustl_static

LOCAL_MODULE    := packer
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := modules/cipher/wrapper.cpp \
                    ... #rest of the cpp code

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes/openssl 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes/precompiled/libssl.so \
            $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes/precompiled/libcrypto.so 
LOCAL_SHARED_MODULES := sslx cryptox
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := sslx
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes/precompiled/libssh.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := cryptox
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes/precompiled/libssh.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And when calling ndk-build I get a dissapointing

```
sslx: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file. Check that /home/user/Development/Tools/sdk/android/ndk/build/core//home/user/Development/Tools/sdk/android/ndk/build/core/includes/precompiled/libssh.so exists  or that its path is correct. Aborting    .  Stop.
```

as you can already guess the path is totally wrong, and what confuses me is that ${LOCAL_PATH} returns correct path for the first batch of includes and a completely wrong one for the .so files ... 
Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution, updated to NDK8c

**step zero**: download and fix the Android NDK 
I dunno how but the ndk has a very interesting flaw, which (in my oppinion) doesn't allow you to compile lot's of stuff, so to be able to compile OpenSSL you need to make a small fix, extract the ndk8c whereever you keep your tools, and then edit the file : 
android-ndk-r8c/build/gmsl/__gmsl
line 512 : 
change line

```
int_encode = $(__gmsl_tr1)$(wordlist 1,$1,$(__gmsl_input_int))
```

with line

```
int_encode = $(__gmsl_tr1)$(wordlist 1,$(words $1),$(__gmsl_input_int))
```

And you're good to go!

**step one** : Download OpenSSL and compile for Android :
either compile a ported version found [**here**](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android)
or Download the official 1.0.0c version of OpenSSL and then compile it for android using the manual provided in the github I linked for the Android compatible version

So the next step is to get the **libssl.so** and **libcrypto.so** 
and put the them in the NDK folder for easy access, so copy them from

```
openssl-folder/libs/armeabi/
```

to

```
android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib
```

this way when compiling you can include the libs using a simple linker switch `-lssl -lcrypto`

**Step two** : get Curl's latest source for **[here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)**

Open the file in Docs/INSTALL and follow the steps needed to make the standalone toolchain and put in your desired folder, and then the tricky part, I needed to have android's source code for the config to continue, even though I have a standalone compiled openssl you can include the header files from there too, in anycase this is the more complicated version so you choose what you do,  I did not choose to evade them so you can go to [Google AOSP site](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) and go trough the steps to build and initialize the environment.

so it would be something like :

1.download,

1. go to root of the source code and run :

   ~: build/envsetup.sh; lunch 1; make;

So finally we need to compile curl with SSL support, so,

**Step three**

extract curl to the desired folder 
(I have a specific desire of disabling everything except http/s to keep the library as small as possible meaning about ~300k, if you want more protocols in your lib, remove the --disable-protocol for the desired protocol)
run the following :

```
make clean

export PATH=/opt/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin:$PATH

export LDFLAGS="\
-lssl \
-lcrypto \
-L/home/user/Development/Tools/sdk/android/ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib"

export CFLAGS="\
-I/home/user/Development/AOSP/2.3.7/system/core/include \
-I/home/user/Development/Tools/sdk/android/ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include"

./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi \
--with-ssl=/home/user/Development/Projects/portingLibs/openssl-android-master \
--disable-ftp \
--disable-gopher \
--disable-file \
--disable-imap \
--disable-ldap \
--disable-ldaps \
--disable-pop3 \
--disable-proxy \
--disable-rtsp \
--disable-smtp \
--disable-telnet \
--disable-tftp \
--without-gnutls \
--without-libidn \
--without-librtmp \
--disable-dict


make



Note that in the block above, if you don't want to use the AOSP source, you could switch 

-I/home/user/Development/AOSP/2.3.7/system/core/include \

with the include folder for your ssl distribution.
```

So finally you have : 
static :

```
curl-7.28.1/lib/.libs/libcurl.a
```

and shared :

```
curl-7.28.1/lib/.libs/libcurl.so.5.3
```

So that's it.. take the file, and compile away :)

Comment: If it is solved, you can mark your solution as answer... all the best

Comment: After applying the fix to __gsml I get the error: Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: /Android.mk
d:/Development/android/android-ndk-r8c/build/core/add-application.mk:165: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
On which platform you ran this? Windows? Is it possible you upload the libcrypto.so libssl.so somewhere?

Comment: can you show us how you linked all of this in the Android.mk file?

Answer (score 0):

@Tancho

I made the change to line __gmsl:512 that you mentioned. Whilst it allowed OpenSSL to compile it also breaks the building of executables by $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE). Before the change my simple hello world application compiles and runs, but after the change it compiles but running it on my Nexus results in a seg fault.

Revert the change and all is well again. I don't know how to fix this, I don't really know what that line does, but this is just a little warning to anybody making that change.

Comment: Interesting.. I have the same change done. And it all works well so far, but still being on the side of caution helps ...

Comment: I did fix this in the end by making the following substitution: from `int_encode = $(__gmsl_tr1)$(wordlist 1,$1,$(__gmsl_input_int))` to `int_encode = $(__gmsl_tr1)$(wordlist 1,$(if $1, $1,0),$(__gmsl_input_int))` This nicely deals with $1 being empty, in which case 0 is returned.