# Fatal Error: openssl/evp.h No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl

I successfully compiled openssl using android ndk build and .so files are built successfully.

I am trying to 'include' built .so files in an android project.

Getting an error in below line:

**#include "openssl/evp.h"**

fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/iedemo/anotherdemo.o] Error 1

However, I am include stdio.h and string.h files.

I am explore /usr/include/openssl directory, I am able find all openssl related .h files here. And, stdio.h and string.h files are present in /usr/include directory.

I have installed **libssl-dev** package too. Command (sudo apt-get install libssl-dev)

Please help me!!

Answer (score 20):

When encountering this problem on Debian or Ubuntu, it can be solved with the following command:

`apt-get install libssl-dev`

Answer (score 3):

For people like me, that uses windows OS and they **accidently** came to this page and the above solutions did not solve their problem, can try the following solution:
I downloaded the OpenSSL executable from the official [website](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), and selected the file with the description that contanins the following line (**Recommended for software developers by the creators of OpenSSL**).
At the time of writing this solution, the file version is (Win64 OpenSSL v3.0.0), and it can be directly downloaded from the following [link](http://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL-3_0_0.exe).

Here is an Image for more declaration:
[image]

After that, I did the following steps:

1. Install the OpenSSL form the .exe file.
2. Copy the **bin** folder directory path (in my case it was C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin) and add it to the system enviroment variables.
3. Copy the **include** folder directory path (in my case it was C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include) and add it to the system enviroment variables.

Then compile the source code that used the openssl library and header files, they should be compiled with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this when building a PHP package using PECL and was able to install the header file as part of **openssl-devel**

On CentOS/RHEL: `yum install openssl-devel`

On Ubuntu/Debian: `apt-get install openssl-devel`

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package openssl-devel`

Comment: on Ubuntu/Debian the package is called ```libssl-dev```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Android.mk` should specify the openssl include directory (not `/usr/include/openssl`, but the one that goes with the files that you built for Android using NDK. Something similar to

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /home/Charan/openssl/include
```

But you will also need to specify the path for `.so` files that you have built, and make sure they are correctly deployed with your app. The things can go messy, but luckily there is a working example: [openSSL using Android's NDK problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285242/openssl-using-androids-ndk-problems#10295653).

Comment: Yes Alex, u are right. I had done in the same way (trial and error method actually). I also copied files to be included into workspace and also specified path for .so file. Can easily messed up...

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error : E: Unable to locate package openssl-devel
you need to add sudo in the beginning
sudo apt-get install openssl-devel