# no such file or directory "<Openssl/evp.h>"

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, header-files

I am trying to run my C program and I use openssl libraries. I keep getting an error stating "No such file or directory #include <openssl/evp.h>" I have installed openssl on Windows and all the paths are added to the system environment. Can someone help me with this issue

I tried reinstalling it and I changed the folder and paths but still nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal Error: openssl/evp.h No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024481/fatal-error-openssl-evp-h-no-such-file-or-directory)