# How to build Openssl for Android on Windows with ndk8?

Tags: android, windows, build, android-ndk, openssl

I tried downloading [OpenSSL-Android](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android#readme). Then run ndk-build which is ndk8c in this case.

I get the error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
d:/Development/android/android-ndk-r8d/build/gmsl/__gmsl:512: *** non-numeric second argument to `wordlist' function: ''.  Stop.
```

When I apply a fix to __gsml as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285242/openssl-using-androids-ndk-problems/10295653#10295653)

I get the error:

```
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: /Android.mk
d:/Development/android/android-ndk-r8c/build/core/add-application.mk:165: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

Or is there a binary I can download? I basically just need libcrypto.so.

This is the Android.mk I am using:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

subdirs := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/,$(addsuffix /Android.mk, \
        crypto \
        ssl \
        apps \
    ))

include $(subdirs)
```

Comment: Can you post your Android.mk?

Comment: I updated the question with Android.mk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.) as Bad Design pointed correctly out the __gsml error is fixed by the following AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.evotegra.aCoDriver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
          android:targetSdkVersion="17"
          android:maxSdkVersion="17" />

</manifest>
```

2.) The error:

```
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: /Android.mk
```

is caused by the line

```
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/Android.mk
```

in jni/**Application**.mk . On Windows the variable $APP_PROJECT_PATH is not set and for that reason it is looking in the root directory for th Android.mk.

This can be fixed by changing the file jni/**Application**.mk to the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.4.3
APP_PROJECT_PATH := $(shell pwd)
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../Android.mk
```

Answer (score 4):

If you get the following error after you run **ndk-build**:

```
android-ndk-r8d/build/gmsl/__gmsl:512: *** non-numeric second argument to `wordlist' function: ''.  Stop.
```

you should add at least "android:minSdkVersion" inside the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
          android:targetSdkVersion="17"
          android:maxSdkVersion="17" />
```

If you want to fix the second error I think you should remove the leading "/" from "/Android.mk" at `,$(addsuffix /Android.mk`

EDIT: I tried building the OpenSSL library for Android project from the Github page you linked and it worked, after I changed AndroidManifest.xml file to something like below:

Note: I'm using **android-ndk-r8d** on a GNU/Linux distribution and I ran **ndk-build** from the root of the project.

You don't have to remove the leading "/".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.jp.algi"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
          android:targetSdkVersion="17"
          android:maxSdkVersion="17" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyJpAndroidAppActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I tried, but it ain't work out. The relevant line in Android.mk now looks `code`subdirs := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/,$(addsuffix Android.mk, \#

Comment: Try to build the files using the following command. This will force complete rebuild and it'll show the commands that the ndk-build script is executing. (i.e. verbose mode)
`ndk-build -B V=1` Also make sure you use the latest Android NDK - android-ndk-r8d

Comment: Using the manifest fixes the __gsml error. But this stupid missing file error remains. This is the output `D:\Development\libs\openssl-android-master>d:\Development\android\android-ndk-r8
d\ndk-build -B V=1
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: /Android.mk
d:/Development/android/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/add-application.mk:165: *** An
droid NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.`

Comment: As you are on Windows, replace "/"es with "\"es

Comment: I tried both `subdirs := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)\,$(addsuffix Android.mk, \ ` and `subdirs := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)\,$(addsuffix \Android.mk, \ ` but the error remains

Comment: I think the makefiles in the Android NDK are filesystem independent, you still get the error if you use the initial contents inside Android.mk? `subdirs := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/,$(addsuffix /Android.mk, \
  crypto \
  ssl \
  apps \
 ))`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23411/discussion-between-tmanthey-and-bad-design)

Answer (score 4):

I used the command dos2unix AndroidManifest.xml and it clears up the error for me. I hope that helps

Comment: this also fixed my problem, the Android build files were in DOS format (on Linux)!

Comment: i have transfered the project form my m$ to a$ and i had the same problem. this solved the issue.