# Does android:versionName have to be numeric (of the form 0.0.0, etc.)?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-manifest

I tried to use `android:versionName=">0.3"` in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file (as a note to myself to bump it on the next release), but the NDK didn't like it:

```
Invalid attribute name: 
C:/Android/android-ndk-r8d/build/gmsl/__gmsl:512: *** non-numeric second argument to `wordlist' function: ''.  Stop.
```

And yet, [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) seem to indicate that I can make my `versionName` whatever I want:

> `android:versionName`
>
> The version number shown to users. This attribute
>   can be set as a raw string or as a reference to a string resource. **The
>   string has no other purpose than to be displayed to users.** The
>   `versionCode` attribute holds the significant version number used
>   internally.

Comment: An interesting tidbit from the GNU Make Standard Library (file `gmsl/__gmsl`):

`Integers [are] represented by lists with the equivalent number of x's. For example the number 4 is x x x x.  The maximum integer that the library can handle as _input_ is __gmsl_input_int which is defined here as 65536` ...fascinating!

Comment: I tried using the same `versionName` as you in my project and didn't get any error. Maybe it is a limitation of the NDK ?

Comment: @nicopico Yes, I only get the NDK error. Do you have an NDK project you can try it with?

Comment: I made some test, it seems the '>' character is invalid for the NDK. You are not limited to number though, as 'version 0.3' seems to work

Comment: Yeah, I experimented with some other special characters as well, like '+' and '?'. Those seemed to be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the NDK uses some interesting GNU Make integer encoding functions on the versionName string. It seems these can handle letters and some special characters (e.g., `?`, `-`, `/`, `\`, and `+`) but not others (e.g., `<` and `>`).

I've opted to append a `.0` to the end of my versionName to indicate that a bump is needed on the next release. In this case, I'm using `0.3.0`.

(for more on GMSL's Integer Arithmetic Functions, see Line 494 of [the source](https://github.com/cloudflare/keyless/blob/master/gmsl/__gmsl))

*Update:*

We've switched to simply appending a `+` character – `0.3+`. Works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I used the command dos2unix AndroidManifest.xml and it clears up the error for me. I hope that helps.

[How to build Openssl for Android on Windows with ndk8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398053/how-to-build-openssl-for-android-on-windows-with-ndk8/15427318?noredirect=1#comment22119338_15427318)

Answer (score 0):

Technically , there are no restrictions about what you put there.

However , please make it as easy to understand as possible , especially for final versions .

For alpha/beta/RC/preview versions , you can put whatever you wish, but still , put some kind of version numbers.

Comment: Hmmm... "no restrictions about what you put there"... How do you explain the NDK error I'm getting?

Comment: can you use : android:versionName="0.3-alpha" instead ? The normal android framework (java) doesn't complain about either of those . You might be able to make the ndk ignore this but sadly i'm not so familiar with the ndk . I know for sure that there are apps that have additional text in the version name . I've tried setting the ">1.0" value and it worked fine for normal android apps.

Comment: I think that would work; I'm going with `.0` as my "to-increment" flag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />` before the application tag.

That worked for me.

Comment: Sorry for making your This a That, but I needed to meet the 6-character change minimum :)

Comment: Did you try this with the NDK and a `versionName` with a `>` in it?