# How to use openssl in Android?

Tags: android, security, ssl, android-ndk, openssl

I have build 2 `so` files from this project(https://github.com/eighthave/openssl-android), now I have `libcrypot.so` and `libssl.so`. **How I can use these libraries in my android application?**. I add the `include/openssl` folder to my project but the headers doesn't compiles, some types can't be recognized.

Comment: You'd need the headers too, won't you?

Comment: The following link provides detailed steps:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10295653/2235132

Comment: Did your update your mk file?

May be this can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669220/ndk-how-to-use-a-generated-so-library-in-another-project.

Comment: There must be over a 1,000 articles written on this topic.  Why would you ask the community to spoof feed you this non-sense?